# Convert this thing to JSON?

Tags: python, json, wrapper

I am using this wrapper here:

https://github.com/mondeja/bittrex_v2

and I use this code here:

```
b = Bittrex(api_key="myapikey", api_secret="mysecretkey")
ba = b.get_balance()

print (ba)
```

The print (ba) puts out this:
https://pastebin.com/x5AVLDXH (it's very long)

how do i convert that into JSON? I know it needs double quote instead of single quote and the Decimal('#') is not right...

Or how would I edit the wrapper to make it print it in to JSON?

Thanks !

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you found any similar questions? Where is your attempt in your question?  Check out how to create a [mcve], as well as read [ask]

Comment: what is the type of (ba)?

Comment: If you spend a few minutes and learn the default format of json, you will know at least how to format a string so that it's "json".  You can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you printed out a dict, not a string. If so, you definitely don't want to convert it that dict to its string representation, and then try to convert that string representation to a JSON string. You just want to encode the dict to JSON directly.

The only obvious tricky bit is converting `Decimal` values to something JSON can handle. You have to decide what you want—maybe just convert to `float`, maybe convert to `float` but also verify that you're not losing any precision in doing so, maybe convert to string, or maybe even convert to some special pickle-ish thing like `{'type': 'decimal.Decimal', 'args': ['0E-8']}`. Which one you want depends entirely on how you're planning to use the JSON later.

Once you've decided what you want to do, it's pretty easy. The docs for [`json.Encoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.default) have an example showing how to support arbitrary iterators by converting them to `list`s, which is pretty easy to adapt to, say, support `Decimal`s by converting them to `float`s:

```
class DecimalEncoder(json.Encoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return float(o)
        return super().default(o)

enc = DecimalEncoder()
json_string = enc.encode(big_dict_with_decimals)
```

I haven't tested against your dict, or laboriously scanned through to see if there are any other weird types. But if there are, you handle them the same way as `Decimal`.